# Creating symbols with multiple colors each from attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-10.3, symbology, query-layer

I use ArcMap 10.3 to create a query layer of points.
The layer is used in a JavaScript API map as a ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer.

Each point has two attributes: point_color and frame_color.
I have 10 different colors for point_color and 10 different colors in frame_color.

The symbol I want is an arrow colored by point_color and a frame colored by frame_color.

I can manually create the symbols as a character marker symbol but then I need to create 10*10 different symbols that deffer only by the colors.

I tried to use LayerDrawingOptions to send a json renderer from the client to the server but there it supports only marker and picture symbols.

Is there a way to create the layer symbology without creating 10*10 different symbols? all symbols are identical except for the point color and frame color.

(I know that I can use a feature layer and render the layer in the client side, but the layer is VERY large and I have performance issues so I want to render the layer is the server side)

Here is a sample of a symbol with red as frame_color and green as point_color:
[image: a sample of a symbol with red as frame_color and green as point_color]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that there is no ArcMap answer to this but if you are also using ArcGIS Pro you may want to experiment with [attribute driven symbology](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/symbols-and-styles/attribute-driven-symbology.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_5E319812B4E14CEBAE02E002305EB0EA):

> Once a layer has been enabled for attribute-driven symbology, you can
>   connect most symbol properties to the value in a feature attribute
>   field or on an expression.
>
> ...
>
> Color properties require string fields containing hexadecimal color
>   values (for example, #CC0055).